# How can I add a number from a cell to be a coordinate in a function?

Tags: excel

Like: I have the number `2` in A2 and in another cell I have `=C2`.

How can I make the "2" in "C2" be read from cell A2?

Image with Problem:
[image]

Comment: @JohnColeman As you can see in the picture there are multiple functions which uses the coordinate, B2, C2, ...., G2 etc. Always ends with 2. or 3, or 4 and so on.

I'd like to make it semi-automatic where I don't have to change every parameter manually with Ctrl+F, Replace all 2-s with 56-s and so on. So I just want to put a number in a cell, and it automatically replaces the 2nd coordinate in the functions.

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Ok... having more informations now, I just got you wrong so my answer is :P

Answer (score 1):

@pnuts was right with INDIRECT. That's what I needed (with an example, from the picture):

=INDIRECT("X!$C$"&A2) instead of

=X!$C$2

Comment: Tried out the example at your link, and one of them was exactly what I needed.